# Deep Learning - Dataflow Matrix Machines

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to understand a newly-created deep learning algorithm called DMM (Dataflow Matrix Machines). I found several papers explaining the applications of that algorithm, while I did not find anything in terms of its structure and logic. It says that DMM is a RNN with vector neurons, but I still could not image a mind map just like LSTM and GRU. Anyone gets any idea about how the algorithm works? Appreciate that!

Comment: Your question is probably better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah I guess you are probably right. Thanks edouard!